# How to configure ESlint for JS application that imports TypeScript modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

### The goal

I have an application that I'd like to migrate to TypeScript progressively. I'd like to be able to:

- import `*.ts` files in Vue single file components
- import `*.ts` files in regular `*.js` files.
- import `*.js` files in `*.ts` files

### My setup

The app was set up using `vue-cli 3.x`. I'm using Airbnb ESLint config.

The majority of the application is written in JS, but all newly added modules are written in TypeScript.

My `.eslint.js` config, before adding TypeScript was:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/airbnb',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
};
```

After I installed `@vue/cli-plugin-typescript`, `typescript` and `@vue/eslint-config-typescript` modules (using the `vue add @vue/typescript` command) I started getting ESLint errors after importing `*.ts` files in `*.js` files. **These were only ESLint errors, not TypeScript or Babel compilation errors**.

So I've modified the `.eslint.js` config as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/airbnb',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/*.js',
        '**/*.vue'
      ],
      parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint',
      },
    },
    {
      files: [
        '**/*.ts'
      ],
      parserOptions: {
        parser: 'typescript-eslint-parser',
      },
    }
  ],
};
```

I've added `override` sections in order to apply different parsers depending on a file extension.

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

So it is a standard `tsconfig.json` that `vue-cli` generates. The only thing I've changed was the `allowJs: true` - thanks to this I can import JS modules that don't have `d.ts` types definitions - that makes the migration easier.

### The question

It all seems to be configured properly, but occasionally I'm getting ESLint errors. It looks like sometimes `babel-eslint` instead of `typescript-eslint-parser` is used to lint `*.ts` files. I don't know how to reproduce it, but I'm almost sure that it happens when I import `*.ts` files in `*.vue` files. Errors are usually gone when I stop and start Webpack again (with `yarn serve`).